# Retrieve ui:inputSelectOption in JS lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, picklist, lightning-apps, lightning-experience

Hi i am unable to get `ui:inputSelectOption` value in js. I have values in `v.accList`which is of type `Account[]`. In alert its getting as undefined.

**CMP**

```
      <ui:inputSelect aura:id="acc" required="true">                        
           <aura:iteration items="{!v.accList}" var="ac">
               <ui:inputSelectOption text="{!ac.Id}" label="{!ac.Name}"/>
           </aura:iteration>
      </ui:inputSelect>
```

**JS**

```
 alert('getaccValue'+(component.find("acc").get("v.text")));
```

Answer (score 4):

[ui:inputSelect](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_ui_inputSelect.htm) stores the selected `text`'s in **`value`** attribute.

You have to specify when you want to retrieve selected Accounts. In my example, it is the `change` Event Attribute.

**Component**

```
<aura:attribute name="selectedAccounts" type="String" />

<ui:inputSelect value="{!v.selectedAccounts}" change="{!c.onAccountChange}">                        
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.accList}" var="ac">
        <ui:inputSelectOption text="{!ac.Id}" label="{!ac.Name}"/>
    </aura:iteration>
</ui:inputSelect>
```

**Controller**

```
onAccountChange: function(component) {
    console.log('Selected Accounts: ', component.get('v.selectedAccounts'));
}
```

Mind that `selectedAccounts` will store `text`'s attributes value. Multiple selected values are separated by `;`.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE!

Answer (score 0):

Providing a simple example of ui:Inputselect

component:

```
<aura:attribute name="contactLevel" type="String[]" default="Primary Contact, Secondary Contact, Other"/>
    <ui:inputSelect aura:id="levels" label="Contact Levels" change="{!c.onSelectChange}">
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.contactLevel}" var="level">
             <ui:inputSelectOption text="{!level}" label="{!level}"/>
        </aura:iteration>
    </ui:inputSelect>
```

Helper:

```
onSelectChange : function(component,event) {
      var selected = component.find("levels").get("v.value");
        alert(selected);
    }
```

if  you look at the helper code i get the select value using the input select attribute 'v.value'.

in your case can you modify the below line to v.value instead of v.text

```
alert('getaccValue'+(component.find("acc").get("v.value")));
```